# How to prevent MSBuild from aborting on signtool errorlevel <> 0

Tags: batch-file, msbuild, wix, signtool

In our current setup build process (WiX 3.9), certain files get digitally signed. To avoid signing an unchange file again, I want to check each file for a signature and skip signing if it's already signed.

I've tried using `signtool.exe verify /pa filename.exe` to check if the file is already signed, and signtool returns with a nonzero ERRORLEVEL if there is no signature. I thought I could check the error code after the call and handle it appropriately:

```
signtool.exe verify /pa %1
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 goto already_signed
rem Sign file now
[...]
goto finished

:already_signed
echo File %1 is already signed, skipping

:finished
```

This works fine if a signature is found and signtool returns 0. But if no signature is found, resulting in a nonzero ERRORLEVEL, MSBuild takes immediate notice of that and displays an error message: `EXEC : SignTool error : No signature found.` One step later, the build fails due to a -1 return code from the signing batch file. In terms of the build process however, there were no errors that would have to be treated like ones.

I've already tried to reset the ERRORLEVEL to 0 after the `signtool verify` call, but that doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you reset `ERRORLEVEL`? One way to ignore any errors in batch file is to have `exit /b 0` at the end. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

As S.T. suggests above, simply add `exit /b 0` below your `:finished` label.  If you want to reset `%ERRORLEVEL%` without exiting your script, you can do `cmd /c exit /b 0`, then `%ERRORLEVEL%` will be reset to zero and your script will continue.

---

Just so I feel like I put some effort into this answer, I'll offer an unrelated tip.  `:)`

Another neat trick for testing exit code status is [conditional execution](http://www.dostips.com/?t=Snippets.ConditionalExecution).

```
>NUL 2>&1 signtool.exe verify /pa "%~1" && (

    echo File %1 is already signed, skipping

) || (

    rem Sign file now
    [...]
    exit /b 0

)
```

The `>NUL 2>&1` stuff simply hides all stdout and stderr output of `signtool.exe`.  The code block after `&&` fires if `signtool` exits 0.  Otherwise, the code block after `||` fires.